# jboss server started.but showing java.net.bind exception ; address already in use

Tags: java, jboss

i am trying to start my local jboss(4.0.1) server,before that modified run.bat file suitable to my environment and also configured jndi data source to local server( here my datasource is remote MSSQL Server database). i see the that jboss server is started , above that it is also showing "java.net.bind exception ;port is already in use " . getting same response after changing port number also. then i figured out that java.exe is running on same port. i colsed that(java.exe) application again started server , but no change in response

here when we are trying to start server , whatever the port number that we gave to jboss , its being used by java.exe while starting server. can you help to make it run

thanks in advance

Comment: It is already started...

Comment: i can that"jboss started" on cmd window, but just above that i can also see that java.net.bind exception ; address already in use

Comment: You have an instance _more_ somewhere.  Stop that first

Comment: How can i check for another instance. what exactly do u mean that, how can i stop that

Comment: SOmething has already occupied the ports JBoss wants to use.  You need to learn how to identify what - that is platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please post exact error message

2) Get a copy of [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx), in addition to running "netstat -a"

3) Check for firewall issues (especially Windows firewall)

4) Read this thread:

- https://community.jboss.org/thread/59995

Comment: unfortunately i cant post copy of that error.  i did netstat -ano  , and found the application(java.exe) which is running on the same port. i closed that application. again i tried to start the server there is no  change in response.   what i found here is ,whenever i am trying to start the server with one particular port , the same  port is being used by java.exe( java.exe is also starting & running)

Comment: That is because java.exe is actually the jboss instance. Every time you start Jboss it is running a JVM (java.exe).

Comment: Again: 1) Please post the exact error (it *will* help!), 2) "TcpView" will give you more information than "netstat", 3) Check your firewall (which could be the whole problem!), and 4) read the thread I cited.  Please post back what happens!

Answer (score 0):

JBOSS uses lots of ports which port is the port number it is complaining about? Do you have multiple ip addresses in the same machine?

Comment: the issue is not with particular port . before assigning port  i am checking for free ports by doing netstat -ano , then i am assigning one free port to jboss then i am starting my server. whatever may be the port i am getting same issue.  and  i think there is only one ip address  with machine

Comment: What type of server are you running on? What is the port number? if you are on Unix starting a port below 1024 and your are not root that might show up as a netbind exception, which could be causing the problem that you are seeing.